# Terminal command ncdu

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I've seen the terminal command `ncdu` is available in various flavors of UNIX. Does anyone know if the same terminal command is available in OS X? Thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: untested, just from Google - http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/ncdu.shtml

Answer (score 29):

No, `ncdu` is not natively available in OSX. But, if you want it, you can install it via [homebrew](http://brew.sh). You just need to type the following to install it:

```
brew install ncdu
```

This is the version available:

```
$ brew info ncdu
ncdu: stable 1.10, HEAD
http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/ncdu.rb
```